# Enter the extracted data using while

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to program an application but I had a problem entering data.
I have two tables, the first one I put data on the trainees and in the second table I enter the points obtained.
I extract the information by using while, but the problem is, when I want to re-enter data, all input has the same name, so the application only enters the last line.

```
while($STAGIAIRE=$resultat->fetch()){?>
        <tr>
        <td>
         <input type="text" name="ID" id="id" class="form-control"
         value="<?php echo $STAGIAIRE['ID']; ?>" readonly/></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="ninscription" id="ninscription" class="form-control"
                                    value="<?php echo $STAGIAIRE['ninscription']; ?>" readonly/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="NOM" id="NOM" class="form-control"
                                    value="<?php echo $STAGIAIRE['NOM']; ?>" readonly/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="PRENOM" id="PRENOM" 
                            class="form-control"
                            value="<?php echo $STAGIAIRE['PRENOM'] ?>" readonly/></td>
          <td scope="col"><input type="text" name="control1" id="control1" class="form-control"/></td>
      <td scope="col"><input type="text" name="control2" id="control2" class="form-control"/></td>
      <td scope="col"><input type="text" name="control3" id="control3" class="form-control"/></td>
      <?php }?>
     <tr><input type="submit" name="submit"value="Enregistre"></tr>



$id=$_POST['ID'];
$ninscription=$_POST['ninscription'];
$nom=$_POST['NOM'];
$prenom=$_POST['PRENOM'];
$control1=$_POST['control1'];
$control2=$_POST['control2'];
$control3=$_POST['control3'];
$requete="insert into controle(ID,PRENOM,NOM,ninscription,control1,control2,control3) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";   
$resultat = $con->prepare($requete);    
$param=array($id,$prenom,$nom,$ninscription,$control1,$control2,$control3);         
$resultat->execute($param);
```

I tried to use for but I haven't reached a solution yet

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is a bit limited, so I must make some assumptions.

I understand that you want to "draw" a table with fixed names of students (readonly fields), and then free-entry fields where you enter the scores for the students ?

So something like :

```
id | name     | first name | score 1    | score 2
---+----------+------------+------------+------------
 1 | <fixed1> | <fixed2>   | free-entry | free-entry 
 2 | <fixed1> | <fixed2>   | free-entry | free-entry 
 3 | <fixed1> | <fixed2>   | free-entry | free-entry
```

Then, on submit of the form, you want to collect for each row a value for score1, score2, ... Correct ?

If that is the aim, each of the INPUT's "control should be an array :

```
<input type="text" id="control1_<?php echo $id; ?>" name="control1[]" class="form-control"/>
```

If you do so, $_POST['control1'] will return an array with the values for control1 gathered over all the rows.